# gpm package not available

Tags: apt

I want to run `mev` (On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) but it is part of the package `gpm` which I don't have. I tried running:

```
sudo apt-get install gpm
```

And I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gpm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'gpm' has no installation candidate
```

It should be in the standard ubuntu sources as far as I know. It was listed in Ubuntu software centre but failed to install. After an `apt-get update` it is now listed as "missing" in the software centre. Any ideas?

Comment: Silly me, didn't say! 12.04, updated above!

Comment: what was the error shown wile you installing it from SC?

Comment: Stupidly I never saved the original error. It was something about can't find package (perhaps "failed to fetch"). It made me think running `apt-get update` would solve it. That is all I remember unfortunately :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gpm is in the universe repository.

[using any method, enable the universe repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding_Ubuntu_Software_Repositories) , then run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gpm
```

Comment: Universe  is on (and so is multiverse) I have also tried changing server from Romanian server to the main server. (Updating each time)

Comment: gpm is in the repository, I can see the file in the mirrors. http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/gpm/download and http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/amd64/gpm/download so, my only other suggestion is to use another mirror and to confirm the package is in the mirror you use. You can also post your repositories.

Comment: I turned the repository OFF, updated. Turned it back on updated AGAIN. Magically sprung back to life. Who knows what was up there!?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.